# Use regex to match multiple words in sequence

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to create a function that will return a string from the text based on these conditions:

1. If 'recurring payment authorized on' in the string, get the 1st text after 'on'
2. If 'recurring payment' in the string, get everything before

Currently I have written the following:

```
#will be used in an apply statement for a column in dataframe
def parser(x):
    x_list = x.split()
    if " recurring payment authorized on " in x and x_list[-1]!= "on":
         return x_list[x_list.index("on")+1]
     elif " recurring payment" in x:
         return ' '.join(x_list[:x_list.index("recurring")])
     else:
         return None
```

However this code looks awkward and is not robust. I want to use regex to match those strings.

Here are some examples of what this function should return:

1. `recurring payment authorized on usps abc` should return `usps`
2. `usps recurring payment abc` should return `usps`

Any help on writing regex for this function will be appreciated. The input string will only contain text; there will be no numerical and special characters

Comment: Have you made any progress towards the regex approach yourself?

Comment: yes, I have used, but it does not work
```c = re.search(r'(?<=authorized on ).*(?=\.|-)',string)
if c:
    print(c.group(0))
```

Comment: Can you give a full example? is this a valid string? `recurring payment authorized on at 17/4/19`?

Comment: Please update your question with examples and your own attempt.

Comment: we really do need to know what the format of the string you want to match is. 1. implies a date, and there are many ways to format a date. I don't know what the second one could be..

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the format of the string...the input string will only contain text...there will be no numeric and special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex with [lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) pattern matching

```
import re

def parser(x):
    # Patterns to search
    pattern_on = re.compile(r'(?<= authorized on )(.*?)(\s+)')
    pattern_recur = re.compile(r'^(.*?)\s(?=recurring payment)')

    m = pattern_on.search(t)
    if m:
        return m.group(0)

    m = pattern_recur.search(t)
    if m:
        return m.group(0)

    return None

tests =  ["recurring payment authorized on usps abc", "usps recurring payment abc", "recurring payment authorized on att xxx xxx", "recurring payment authorized on 25.05.1980 xxx xxx", "att recurring payment xxxxx", "12.14.14. att recurring payment xxxxx"]


for t in tests:
    found = parser(t)
    if found:
        print("In text: {}\n Found: {}".format(t, found))
```

**Output**

```
In text: recurring payment authorized on usps abc
 Found: usps 
In text: usps recurring payment abc
 Found: usps 
In text: recurring payment authorized on att xxx xxx
 Found: att 
In text: recurring payment authorized on 25.05.1980 xxx xxx
 Found: 25.05.1980 
In text: att recurring payment xxxxx
 Found: att 
In text: 12.14.14. att recurring payment xxxxx
 Found: 12.14.14. att
```

**Explanation**

[Lookahead and Lookbehind pattern matching](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

> *Regex Lookbehind*
>
> (?<=foo)  Lookbehind  Asserts that what immediately precedes the current
>   position in the string is foo

So in pattern: r'(?<= authorized on )(.*?)(\s+)'

```
foo is " authorized on "
(.*?) - matches any character (? causes it not to be greedy)
(\s+) - matches at least one whitespace
```

So the above causes (.*?) to capture all characters after " authorized on " until the first whitespace character.

> *Regex Lookahead*
>
> (?=foo)   Lookahead   Asserts that what immediately follows the current position in the string is foo

So with: r'^(.*?)\s(?=recurring payment)'

```
foo is 'recurring payment'
^ - means at beginning of the string
(.*?) - matches any character (non-greedy)
\s - matches white space
```

Thus, (.*?) will match all characters from beginning of string until we get whitespace followed by "recurring payment"

**Better Performance**
Desirable since you're applying to Dataframe which may have lots of columns.

Take the pattern compilation out of the parser and place it in the module (33% reduction in time).

```
def parser(x):
    # Use predined patterns (pattern_on, pattern_recur) from globals
    m = pattern_on.search(t)
    if m:
        return m.group(0)

    m = pattern_recur.search(t)
    if m:
        return m.group(0)

    return None

 # Define patterns to search
pattern_on = re.compile(r'(?<= authorized on )(.*?)(\s+)')
pattern_recur = re.compile(r'^(.*?)\s(?=recurring payment)')

tests =  ["recurring payment authorized on usps abc", "usps recurring payment abc", "recurring payment authorized on att xxx xxx", "recurring payment authorized on 25.05.1980 xxx xxx", "att recurring payment xxxxx", "12.14.14. att recurring payment xxxxx"]
```

Comment: this matches only `25` from `recurring payment authorized on 25.05.1980 `. I doubt it can be used reliably

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining what `(?<= authorized on )(.*?)(\s+)` and `^(.*?)\s(?=recurring payment)` do?

Comment: @user9933484--added an explanation section to answer.  Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: ye pretty nice, they just have to keep in mind that `^` in the second one limits the applicability a bit, but if it's always at the start of the string why not

Comment: @KGS--since the **(.*?)** capture pattern occurs first, it will pick up everything at the beginning of the string so the **^** is actually not necessary.  I just placed it for emphasis but think it is redundant and the output is the same in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this level of complexity requires RegEx.

Hoping that RegEx is not a strict requirement for you here's a solution not using it:

```
examples = [
'stuff more stuff recurring payment authorized on ExampleA useless data',
'other useless data ExampleB recurring payment',
'Not matching phrase payment example authorized'
]


def extract_data(phrase):
    result = None
    if "recurring payment authorized on" in phrase:
        result = phrase.split("recurring payment authorized on")[1].split()[0]
    elif "recurring payment" in phrase:
        result = phrase.split("recurring payment")[0]
    return result


for example in examples:
    print(extract_data(example))
```

**Output**

```
ExampleA
other useless data ExampleB
None
```

Comment: Doesn't requirement 2 state: "If 'recurring payment' in the string, get everything before"  So shouldn't 'other useless data ExampleB recurring payment' -> 'other useless data ExampleB'?  I agree it's not clear since examples are not provided. of this case.

Comment: Hi @DarrylG! I've changed my code, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is any faster, but Python has conditionals:

- If `authorized on` is present then

  - match the next substring of non-space characters else
  - match everything that occurs before `recurring`

Note that the result will be in capturing group 2 or 3 depending on which matched.

```
import re

def xstr(s):
    if s is None:
        return ''
    return str(s)

def parser(x):
    # Patterns to search
    pattern = re.compile(r"(authorized\son\s)?(?(1)(\S+)|(^.*) recurring)")

    m = pattern.search(t)
    if m:
        return xstr(m.group(2)) + xstr(m.group(3))

    return None

tests =  ["recurring payment authorized on usps abc", "usps recurring payment abc", "recurring payment authorized on att xxx xxx", "recurring payment authorized on 25.05.1980 xxx xxx", "att recurring payment xxxxx", "12.14.14. att recurring payment xxxxx"]


for t in tests:
    found = parser(t)
    if found:
        print("In text: {}\n Found: {}".format(t, found))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single regex and without explicit lookahead nor lookbehind.

Please let me know if this works, and how it performs against @DarryIG's solution.

```py
import re
from collections import namedtuple


ResultA = namedtuple('ResultA', ['s'])
ResultB = namedtuple('ResultB', ['s'])


RX = re.compile('((?P<init>.*) )?recurring payment ((authorized on (?P<authorized>\S+))|(?P<rest>.*))')


def parser(x):
    '''https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600852/use-regex-to-match-multiple-words-in-sequence

    >>> parser('recurring payment authorized on usps abc')
    ResultB(s='usps')
    >>> parser('usps recurring payment abc')
    ResultA(s='usps')
    >>> parser('recurring payment authorized on att xxx xxx')
    ResultB(s='att')
    >>> parser('recurring payment authorized on 25.05.1980 xxx xxx')
    ResultB(s='25.05.1980')
    >>> parser('att recurring payment xxxxx')
    ResultA(s='att')
    >>> parser('12.14.14. att recurring payment xxxxx')
    ResultA(s='12.14.14. att')
    '''
    m = RX.match(x)
    if m is None:
        return None  # consider ValueError
    recurring = m.groupdict()['init'] or m.groupdict()['rest']
    authorized = m.groupdict()['authorized']
    if (recurring is None) == (authorized is None):
        raise ValueError('invalid input')
    if recurring is not None:
        return ResultA(recurring)
    else:
        return ResultB(authorized)
```